# Is it better idea to save elements in yml file?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, yaml

I'm writing automated tests using Selenium WebDriver with Ruby. So, I'm thinking to keep elements in another file and actual code in another file. And for Ruby, I found `yaml` gem which allows to store data and access it. Hence I stored elements in `lib.yml` and test code in `test.rb` as following:

**lib/lib.yml**

```
homepage:
  frame: 'mainPage'
  email: 'loginPage-email'
  password: 'loginPage-password'
  login_button: 'btnLogin'
```

**tests/test.rb**

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'yaml'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox

driver.get 'http://www.abc.com'

config = YAML.load_file('./lib/lib.yml')

driver.switch_to.frame(config['homepage']['frame'])

email = driver.find_element(:id, config['homepage']['email'])
password = driver.find_element(:id, config['homepage']['password'])

email.clear
email.send_keys 'abc@gmail.com'

password.clear
password.send_keys 'password'

driver.find_element(:id, config['homepage']['login_button']).click

driver.quit
```

This way maintenance becomes easier. I just want to make sure if doing so is a good way or not. I'm asking because I'm trying this first time and don't know what difficulties I'll run into if I choose this for larger project.

I know, using Page object model, we can achieve same thing. But I don't know about Page object. So should I avoid using `yml` gem and directly go for `page object` gem?

Also, can someone explain how using `yml` will not be good idea(if it's not)?

**Note:**

1. In above code, `config['homepage']['something']` is repetitive code. I'll write method to avoid repetition for that.

Comment: This looks a little bit like a "inner platform" pattern. Since you are going to write helper methods anyway, why don't you start with that first and hardcode their functionality. Later you can add the planned YAML functionality - if it really helps - and just change your helpers.

Comment: Hm... good idea! Thanks  Daniel Rikowski! I'll try to implement this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah this definitely is useful... It keeps the changes to minimum when there is UI change in future.. You always have just one place to edit... Is there any data you have to pass to your code? How are storing the automation data passed to your test.. The only concern might be you might end up with too many yaml files which could be difficult to keep track...

Comment: Thanks user2660163! Hm... adding too many files could be difficult to track. I think, I'll have put elements related to same functionality/scenario/page in same file and name yaml files properly. This way, it would help me track them easily.

Comment: Right, distributing elements according to pages will help you keep track of the elements... Just out of curiosity, Is the data read from a yaml file an "in memory" operation? or a "file operation"?

Comment: okay, if its a file operation than I would suggest you to place the same data (As in the yaml file) in an in-memory file.

Comment: By in memory file I mean a ruby file, where you can declare your element data in an interface. You can have multiple files with interfaces (clubbing relative ones in a single ruby file). Usage of yaml also works but there will be slight overhead in file operations (which is pretty less) so if time is not a contraint you can go ahead with yaml otherwise declare in-memory. Even if declare data in a ruby file it will still keep the changes to minimum when UI changes.

Answer (score 1):

In your specific case I don't see how this adds much value. Half of the settings (frame, login_button) won't change for your tests, so I suggest leaving them directly in the code where they are used. The html structure is not something that usually changes.

The other two values (email, password) seem like they might change when you want to try out different users (i.e. different cases). If you have one test with several example inputs then I suggest using a more readable solution as Cucumber.

(I'd suggest using capybara anyway for testing browser interaction, as it abstracts away many details of the underlying driver)

Apart from that, yaml *is* usually the ruby way for storing configuration.

Comment: I agree with you that the settings which won't change forever should be in code itself. But the code I mentioned above is just for example purpose. I just want to know overall effect of using `yml` in case of Selenium tests. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I added one more step: Declared locator (id, name etc) in the yaml itself.

```
Ex:(yaml) 
Declared env.rb which load the environment from yaml files
env.yml:
    LOGIN:
       UserName:  {id:  UserName}
       Password: {id: Password}
       RememberME: {id: RememberMe}
      Submit: {xpath: "//input[@value='Log On']"}

Then added "pages\Login.rb"

#Loads all objects from yaml 
    def get_objects 
     username=@browser.find_element( $object_array['LOGIN']['UserName'])
     password=@browser.find_element( $object_array['LOGIN']['Password'])
     remember_me=@browser.find_element( $object_array['LOGIN']['RememberME'])
     submit= @browser.find_element($object_array['LOGIN']['Submit'])
    end



#Added methods in this class like
    def loginas(uname,pass)
      username.send_keys uname
      password.send_keys pass
      remember_me.click
      submit.click      
    end #loginas_siteadmin

Created Tests file Login_tests.rb

    lp=LoginPage::new(@browser)
    lp.navigate
    lp.loginas('SiteAdmin','password123')
```

This way your scripts and maintainable and most importantly you are free of any other external gem or dependency.